# Bullet Proof Text

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I have no idea what is going on, but grep, awk, sed have been rendered neutered in the face of a series of text files. Simply put, they wil not work. I cannot pattern match over a range with awk with proven personal and public examples. I cannot get sed to use the p or i options, but s still works. Both awk and sed have the odd behavior of simply printing everything regardless if the pattern matches or not. And grep will find a word (via regex or string) but if I go to exclude the word (-v) it erases everything. And I mean everything.

I don't think pasting code will be useful, but I am amenable to this. I don't think pasting text will work either.

Is there some super secret setting that renders these programs daft? I've made sure everything is saved in utf-8, and have run tr -d '\r\n' and its permutations over everything. This is a linux box and I am beating my head against the table.

All of this is being done in a linux environment with BASH.

Any ideas?

Comment: Some kind of unexpected invisible characters?

Comment: tr should of gotten anything.  But if you have any ideas for \Kr (kryptonite) lurking let me know.

Comment: `tr -d '\r\n'` will delete all carriage returns *and* linefeeds in the file, turning it into one huge line. And from some of what you've described, it sounds like your file might just be one huge line... In any case, I think you need to take a close look at the file's contents with something like a hex dump, and see what's really in there.

Comment: See the section about DOS line endings on the [`bash` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) for some troubleshooting tips. The [`character-encoding tag` wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info) also has some ideas at least for how to articulate a moderately intelligent question. Without *any* diagnostics, all we can offer is blind guesses.

Comment: I think you should paste a sample of non-working code and give us a link (don't paste, it might ruin encodings) to download one of these invulnerable files. To make sure we have the exact same file you do, take a sha1sum of it and post that as well.

Comment: Check your file: `cat --show-nonprinting file`

Comment: As already mentioned by Cyrus, pass the file through `cat --show-nonprinting file` or worst case, through `xxd < file`.

Comment: taken from very far: you did not play around with any shared libraries these programs need? They do work as expected on "normal" files?

Answer (score 1):

@GordonDavisson seems to have nailed it. Your `tr -d '\r\n'` turned your file into one long line without an ending newline so you should expect `grep -v <something that appears in the file>` to output nothing [at best] since everything's on one line and, while some will do their best with it, you shouldn't even expect UNIX tools to be able to handle it at all since it's not a valid text file without an ending newline. Look:

```
$ cat file
the
quick
brown
dog
$ grep bro file
brown
$ grep -v bro file
the
quick
dog

$ tr -d '\r\n' < file > file2

$ cat file2
thequickbrowndog$
$ grep bro file2
thequickbrowndog
$ grep -v bro file2
$
```

Not sure what you wanted to achieve with that `tr` so not sure what to advise you to do with the file now.